# Why react native hangs on 59%?

Tags: linux, reactjs, ubuntu-16.04, react-native

I am learning react-native.

When I run react-native run-android, I get following error:

```
Thread(png-cruncher_20) has a null payload
> Building 59% > :app:mergeDebugResources
```

I found a solution which asks me to run following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32stdc++6
```

But running these commands says I have unmet or uninstalled dependencies. I tried to install them too, then they say same thing for different dependencies and it goes on and never stop. Thus, I cannot install any of the above packages.

Can't I install all these dependencies at once ? Or is there any other solution ?

Comment: this seems more like a question about your OS and what is installed, than a question about react specifically.  What OS and version are you working from?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: there are multiple articles related to ubuntu 16.04 64 bit having issues with these 32 bit libraries.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/804584/command-to-install-32bit-packages-lib32z1-lib32ncurses5-lib32bz2-1-0-lib32stdc/804588#804588, for example.